# Publish class library Generated Document XML?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publish, xml-documentation

I have a class library Portable Area, an ASP.NET project that has the reference to the class library.

The class library has a build configuration from Visual Studio 2012 that will output XML Dcoumentation file.

I setted the Output path to:

bin\

XML documentation file: bin\DocumentFile.XML

When I do the debugging, it generates fine.

I have also ensure that the configuration for Debug and Release have same output path.

But when I publish this ASP.NET project, the XML documentation from the class library is not also published to the publish folder.

How can make the XML file generated even when I do the publish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Property of XML file and change Build action to content option, might be resolved your problem

Comment: Omg, you are right.  I thought it just didn't generated at all.  I had to show all files that not in project and just include the XML file into project and set to Copy as always.  Thanks.